# Bootstrap Dropdown Hoverable Dropdown menu using CSS only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make this part of my code hoverable using CSS only but didn't work, I followed steps right here, http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp , But i couldn't put anything correctly in its place on my code, I either make the  hoverable or instead i make the entire .list hoverable but yet the .list doesn't work hover hover

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <div class="list">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">4</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">5</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

CSS (What I've tried by myself)

```
<style>
.dropdown-menu {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.dropdown-menu:hover > .list {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange structure, but the core of the issue was in your targetting of the wrong classes.

```css
.dropdown{
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <div class="list">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">4</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">5</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Well, that working but it disappears directly after i move the mouse from "Dropdown", In W3 it stays as i keep moving on it.

Comment: Yeah, because you need to wrap the dropdown inside of the <a> element. Do you want me to fix that for you? I didn't want to touch your html.

Comment: Yes Please, If you have time, I just took it from Bootstrap Navbar page and put the .dropdown-item inside a .list so i can use grids and things like that after.

Comment: Updated. Actually, I just changed the hover event to act on li element instead.

Comment: Excuse me, But one last question, Can i make the hover only for PCs but expandable onclick on other devices? It seems that i need to learn JavaScript for the OnClick.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with javascript. If you're really really new, look into jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-menu:hovern .list {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

this would work, You forgot to remove the '>' from the code that didn't allow css to access the list class, just remove'>' from the code and it may work.

in CSS, any class present in another class can be targeted by just writing the class name with '.'operator.

example- HTML code:

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.A .B{
}
```

this is how you access a subClass with parent class.

Comment: did you made the changes in the bootstap.css file? Because what I can get from it is that, you are trying to overwrite the onclick function already applien in the bootstrap.css file. So either make the changes bootstrap.css or remove or just comment that section in bootstrap file and then try running this code

Comment: i'm using CDN instead of the .css file